# Swagger php different versions of a definition

Tags: php, api, swagger, swagger-php

I am setting Swagger for my API using annotations swagger-php. What I can't get my head around is how to define different definitions of a resourse.

I have a `User` class that has id, email, password, and phone.

The following operation receive respective paramaters

`create`: `email`, `password`, `phone`

`update`: `email`, `password`, `phone`, `oldPassword`

The `get` opration will return `id`, `email`, `phone` + some related models which are created and updated through different endpoints.

So every one of these uses it's own definition of `User` and I am unsure how to define it neatly without just duplicating the properties across different definitions (DRY).

I thought about creating a

`BaseUser` with `email`, `phone`,

then `NewUser` that would add `password`

then `UpdateUser` adding `oldPassword`

and `FullUser` combining the `BaseUser` with the read-only relationship properties.

But damn, it's so complicated for such a trivial thing and all this reference hell with then be reflected in the swagger.json.

Is there a solution for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Swagger Definition with `extends` feature.

1. Make BaseUser with email and password

```
/**
 * Class BaseUser
 * @SWG\Definition(
 *     type="object",
 *     required={"email", "password"},
 * )
 */
class BaseUser
{
    /**
     * User's email address.
     *
     * @var string
     * @SWG\Property(example="email@example.com")
     */
    public $email;

    /**
     * User's password.
     *
     * @var string
     * @SWG\Property(example="password")
     */
    public $password;
}
```

2. Create UserCreate definition extending BaseUser

```
/**
 * Class UserCreate
 * @SWG\Definition(
 *     type="object",
 *     required={"phone_number"},
 * )
 */
class UserCreate extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * User's phone number.
     *
     * @var integer
     * @SWG\Property(example=9876543210)
     */
    public $phone_number;
}
```

3. Create UserUpdate definition extending UserCreate

```
/**
 * Class UserUpdate
 * @SWG\Definition(
 *     type="object",
 *     required={"old_password"},
 * )
 */
class UserUpdate extends UserCreate
{
    /**
     * User's old or existing password.
     *
     * @var string
     * @SWG\Property(example="old-password")
     */
    public $old_password;
}
```

You can extend your definitions at any level but the thing is that your required attributes must be listed in your last definition.

[The output will be as shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBlC0.png)